# What does a ':' in Markdown do?

Tags: php, html, css, markdown, mustache

I've been working on my resume and decided to drop the word document and switch to markdown. I forked [markdown-resume](https://github.com/cable729/markdown-resume) and have been working on porting over my resume, but have run into some problems. I'm not all too familiar with markdown and css, but I managed to change some things to my liking.

I'm trying to figure out how

```
### Education {#education}

University of Nebraska-Lincoln
: *Bachelor of Science in Computer Engineering*
  __2011 - 2015__
```

gets translated to

```
<dl>
  <dt>University of Nebraska-Lincoln</dt>
  <dd><em>Bachelor of Science in Computer Engineering</em>
  <strong>2011 - 2015</strong></dd>
</dl>
```

I know that `build.php` runs

```
$resume   = file_get_contents($source);
$resume = Markdown($resume);
$resume = SmartyPants($resume);
```

and then renders using

```
$m = new Mustache;
$rendered = $m->render(
    $template,
    array(
        'title'  => $title,
        'style'  => $style,
        'resume' => $resume,
        'reload' => $refresh_dev
    )
);
```

where `$template` is the html base template and $style is an `AssetCollection` containing `"/assets/css/*.css"`.

I think the semicolon might have something to do with it. Here's a link to the [css files being used](https://github.com/cable729/markdown-resume/tree/master/assets/css).

Comment: Im guessing in this case thats a delimiter. For every one of those a certain action is made. Similar to `*` and `_`

Comment: Well, from the markdown docs, `*...* = _..._ <em>...</em>` and `**...** = __...__ = <strong>...</strong>`. I couldn't find anything about semi-colons, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Colon treats the current line as a definition for the previous line.

Example:

```
Markdown
: A nifty little tool to write richly formatted text using plain text formatting!

Stackoverflow
: A community of brilliant minds.
```

Comment: It's worth noting that this is an extension of the Markdown spec implemented as part of PHP Markdown Extra: http://michelf.ca/projects/php-markdown/extra/#def-list